# Extending Marc Gravell's Dynamic Linq OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, sql-order-by, linq-to-objects

I found Marc Gravell's dynamic order by great:

[Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby)

I've put it in a class, `LinqHelper`.  In this class I also have created two new classes, so that in my code I can do this:

```
var q = db.tblJobHeaders;

LinqHelper.OrderByCollection OBys = new LinqHelper.OrderByCollection();
OBys.AddOrderBy("some field", true);
OBys.AddOrderBy("anotherfield", false);
OBys.ExecuteOrderBys(q);
```

The classes to acheive this are:

```
/// <summary>
/// A collection of order bys
/// </summary>
public class OrderByCollection
{
    private ArrayList Orderings = new ArrayList();

    public OrderByCollection(){ }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add an order by to this collection
    /// </summary>
    public void AddOrderBy(string Field, bool Descending)
    {
        OrderByObj NewObj = new OrderByObj(Descending, Field);
        this.Orderings.Add(NewObj);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the order bys
    /// </summary>
    public IOrderedQueryable<T> ExecuteOrderBys<T>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> source)
    {
        int ExecutionIndex = 0;
        foreach (OrderByObj O in this.Orderings)
        {
            if (ExecutionIndex == 0)
            {
                if (O.Descending)
                    source = LinqHelper.OrderByDescending(source, O.Field);
                else
                    source = LinqHelper.OrderBy(source, O.Field);
            }
            else
            {
                if (O.Descending)
                    source = LinqHelper.ThenByDescending(source, O.Field);
                else
                    source = LinqHelper.ThenBy(source, O.Field);
            }
            ExecutionIndex++;
        }
        return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)source;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// An order by object
/// </summary>
private class OrderByObj
{
    public bool Descending { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }

    public OrderByObj(bool IsDescending, string DatabaseField)
    {
        this.Descending = IsDescending;
        this.Field = DatabaseField;
    }
}
```

Howver I'm pretty new to passing Linq vars through to functions (the  confuses me a bit).  I currently get the error on:

```
OBys.ExecuteOrderBys(q);
```

Which gives the error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'LinqHelper.OrderByCollection.ExecuteOrderBys(System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

I'm a bit confused about this if anyone could help, am I passing the `var q` in properly, and then returning it properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet the type of `q` is `IQueryable<T>` and not `IOrderedQueryable<T>`. Just changing the signature should work, because you start with `OrderBy`.

Then you will need an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` for the `ThenBy`s. You can just cast it, because you know for sure that you have an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` from the previous call to either `OrderBy` or `ThenBy`.

If you don't like the idea of the cast, you need some changes:

```
public IOrderedQueryable<T> ExecuteOrderBys<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
{
    if(!this.Orderings.Any())
        throw new InvalidOperationException("You need to add orderings");
    IOrderedQueryable<T> ordered;
    if (this.Orderings[0].Descending)
        ordered = LinqHelper.OrderByDescending(source, this.Orderings[0].Field);
    else
        ordered = LinqHelper.OrderBy(source, this.Orderings[0].Field);
    foreach(var ordering in this.Orderings.Skip(1))
    {
        if (ordering.Descending)
            ordered = LinqHelper.ThenByDescending(source, ordering.Field);
        else
            ordered = LinqHelper.ThenBy(source, ordering.Field);
    }
    return ordered;
}
```

Note your code will fail spectacularly if you don't add any orderings, because of the cast to `IOrderedQueryable<T>` in the end. You could change the return type to `IQueryable<T>` (which loses the ability to "attach" more OrderBys later), or throw if there are no orderings, like I did.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work  but throws errors on the 'ThenBy' statements in `ExecuteOrderBys` : `The type arguments for method 'LinqHelper.ThenBy<T>(System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<T>, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: Super this seems to work great!  I'll just check it all works fine thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Tom: a side note: please don't use `ArrayList`. Treat `ArrayList` as obsolete. Use `List<object>`, or in your case `List<string>`, which should work fine.

Comment: Sorry about that last comment. I mean `List<Ordering>`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, just a quick question, are all these order bys deferred execution like a regular linq query? (I think it is,just checking)

Comment: @Tom: Yes, Marc's implementation just calls the regular `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` methods. It needs to use magic (reflection) to make this work with strings, but the end result is the same..